# Node.js stream: stream appears freezed

Tags: node.js, typescript, csv, stream

I'd like to create a simple csv parser (using the csv module) and handle the error, when the file does not exist.

If I comment out the sleep methods, the code reaches the Finally (and writes out Some error).

What do I miss? In my real example, I do need to do some awaited task there.

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import * as csv from 'csv';
import { finished } from 'stream';

type TabularFileType = 'csv' | 'tsv';

const DELIMITER_BY_TYPE: Record<TabularFileType, string> = {
    csv: ',',
    tsv: '\t',
};

/**
 * Creates an (async) iterable from a tabular file at `path`
 * @param type type of file, could be `'csv'` or `'tsv'`
 * @param path path of the file to be loaded
 * @param columns an array of string defining the property names of the columns
 * @param options can specify some optional things,
 * like encoding (will decode using iconv-lite)
 * and skip some header lines (with the help of `fromLines`)
 */
export function tabularStream<T>(
    type: TabularFileType,
    path: string,
    columns: string[],
    options?: { encoding?: string; fromLine?: number }
): csv.parser.Parser {
    console.info('About to read file from "%s"', path);
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(path);

    const result = stream.pipe(
        csv.parse({
            delimiter: DELIMITER_BY_TYPE[type],
            fromLine: options?.fromLine,
            columns,
        })
    );

    finished(stream, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            result.destroy(new Error('whoops'));
        }
    });

    console.log("About to return");
    return result;
}

const sleep = (millis: number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));

(async () => {
    console.log('wait a bit');
    await sleep(100);
    console.log('waited');
    const p = tabularStream('csv', 'nonexistent', []);
    // If you comment it out, ended will appear on output
    await sleep(100);
    console.log('after sleep')  ;
    try {
        for await(const record of p) {
            console.log('Got a record', record);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Some error!', e);
    } finally {
        console.log('Finally!');
    }
})();
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce any problems. Used **ts-node** v10.2.1 with **node** v16.13.0. But I would suggest placing the call to `tabularStream` inside the `try` block.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an excerpt of the .csv file as a gist, so the issue is reproducible?

Comment: @jorgenkg: nonexistent: so there is no such file. The code is complete.

Comment: The code breaks since the `stream` variable is missing an `"error"` listener. The error does not propagate to the subsequently piped stream middleware. However, the code could be restructured to use `stream.pipeline()`, which implicitly both pipe data and handles errors.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jorgenkg/931c9ec33a045f79f4cedf3659309ac6

Comment: @jorgenkg Why don't you convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterintuitively, each stream middleware needs its own `"error"` listener to handle stream errors correctly.

The `stream` variable is missing the error listener in OP's snippet. Consequently, an unhandled (asynchronous) error is raised when reading a non-existing file.

```js
export function tabularStream(...) {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(path); // <-- stream needs an "error" listener
    const result = stream.pipe(csv.parse(...));
    ...
}
```

(Un)commenting the "sleep" step changes how the snippet executes by evaluating the asynchronous, unhandled error sooner rather than later.

Rather than having to include an `"error"` listener on all stream middlewares, nodejs offers a `stream.pipeline()` function that handles both piping data and errors.

```js
export function tabularStream(...) {
  const result: stream.Readable = stream.pipeline(
    fs.createReadStream(path),
    csv.parse(...),
    error => (error && result.emit("error", error))
  );
  ...
  return result;
} // remember to add `error` listener to the returned variable
```

Comment: Just one small thing I don't get: why the safeguard `error &&`? Can the error handler called with `null`/`undefined`?

Comment: No, that would still be considered an error. Emitting an `"error"` in event-driven code in NodeJS amounts to the same as throwing an error in procedural code. All `EventEmitters` that might emit an `"error"` event must have an error listener; otherwise, it will result in an UnhandledException. Personal opinion: I would, by convention, never `throw null`, nor would I emit an error event with a null object.